# Select by location using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, layers, select-by-location

I try to select by location all layers that intersect layer named "frame", and then remove from the maps other layers that don't intersect it. Finally, i want to print the all the removed layers and the remain layers in the table of content.

This is my table of content:

[image]

UPDATE CODE:
I using this code:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = True  
env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\Project"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd'):
        print '---' ,mxdname, '---'  
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(env.workspace, mxdname))  
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "" ,df):
                if lyr.isGroupLayer == True: continue
                if lyr.isRasterLayer == True: continue
                arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyr.dataSource, "lyr")
                frameLyr = r"G:\desktop\Project\layers\frame.shp"
                arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lyr", "INTERSECT", frameLyr)
                if int(arcpy.GetCount_management("lyr").getOutput(0)) == 0:
                        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
                        print u'Removed '+unicode(lyr) + ' lyr'
                print lyr.name
mxd.save()        
del mxd
```

This code works, but i get this result and i wonder if i can shorten this code, so i will get print only one time the removed layer and not twice as below:

```
>>> 
--- Project.mxd ---
REMOVED LYR
Removed point2 lyr
point2
Removed wells lyr
wells
Removed point lyr
point
Removed river lyr
river
Removed line lyr
line
Removed openSpace lyr
openSpace
frame
land use
>>>
```

[image]

Comment: I would not use `continue` statements in code like this.  Have you tried using just nested `if` statements instead?  Also, you should be able to present a much more minimalist code snippet. By focussing on just one MXD that is giving the wrong result you can get rid of the iteration through all the MXDs for a simpler test from which you can better explain what you mean by an "unwanted result".

Comment: Your code is still iterating through the MXD files returned by `arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd')` and does not appear to be the code run to produce that output.  Once that is addressed the output would be easier to interpret if you showed us what the Table of Contents of what one MXD contains in the way of layers, and how those layers sit in relation to the frame polygon.

Comment: ok, then this question will not be on hold?

Comment: Whenever your question is edited it goes into the review queue to be assessed for re-opening but whether that happens will depend on the level of improvement. What I described is the improvement that I think this question needs.

Comment: @PolyGeo What's wrong with "continue"? Aside from being in a compound statement, his use of it seems to be exactly how the Python docs demonstrate it's use.

Comment: @Tom I commented that I would not use continue and would nest if statements instead which is because I think it is easier code to write for someone new to Python. However, my actual concern with this question is mainly around not eliminating the iteration through the MXD list to enable a shorter code snippet to be presented.

Answer (score 0):

To try and help you debug/improve (I'm still not clear which you are trying to do) your code I suggest using the test code below:

```
import arcpy,os

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"G:\desktop\Project\Project.mxd")  
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "" ,df)
    if lyr.isGroupLayer == True: continue
    if lyr.isRasterLayer == True: continue
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyr.dataSource, "lyr")
    frameLyr = r"G:\desktop\Project\layers\frame.shp"
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lyr", "INTERSECT", frameLyr)
    if int(arcpy.GetCount_management("lyr").getOutput(0)) == 0:
        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
        print u'Removed '+unicode(lyr) + ' lyr'
    print lyr.name
mxd.save()        
del mxd
```

If that is not producing the expected output, or if it throws an error then show us exactly what is output when it is run and describe precisely how what you observe being output departs from what you would expect to see, and why.

The why part is where a zoomed in picture of the Table of Contents from `G:\desktop\Project\Project.mxd`, and its layers drawn in relation to your frame.shp would be invaluable.

Comment: PolyGeo, where can i add the result of your code?

Comment: @newGIS The type of Q&A you are trying to do is quite unorthodox but I suggest you put it at the end of your question prefaced by "This is the result of running the script in [@PolyGeo's answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/184162/115): ".

Comment: Actually, I think this test should replace the code in your question so that you can just say "when I run this code ... this is the result", but keep reading and re-reading your question to make sure it flows.